# Grouping by result of sum

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm converting tables for a client and some elements need to span across multiple columns. Each element has the attribute `aid:ccols` which indicates across how many columns this value should span. I'm trying to group these elements until the sum of `aid:ccols` equals `basictable/@aid:tcols` and so on.

I tried multiple things by using `xsl:for-each`, `group-by` but nothing seems to work.

```
<basictable xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" aid:table="table" aid:trows="7" aid:tcols="3">
      <cell-tab-tit-center aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="3">1. Les « salaires » du mois</cell-tab-tit-center>
      <cell-tab-txt-left aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="67.53149606308261">Salaire mensuel</cell-tab-txt-left>
      <cell-tab-txt-left aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="2">Arrêté à la date de rupture du contrat (fin du préavis, même en cas de dispense par l’employeur).</cell-tab-txt-left>
      <cell-tab-txt-left aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="67.53149606308261">Rappels éventuels</cell-tab-txt-left>
      <cell-tab-txt-left aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="2">Vérifier si des rappels restent dus.</cell-tab-txt-left>
      <cell-tab-txt-left aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="67.53149606308261">Primes annuelles</cell-tab-txt-left>
      <cell-tab-txt-left aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="2">Vérifier si les primes annuelles sont dues au prorata.</cell-tab-txt-left>
      <cell-tab-txt-left aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="67.53149606308261">Ind. comp. cp N-1</cell-tab-txt-left>
      <cell-tab-txt-left aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="147.40157480314957">Contrôler le solde de cp.</cell-tab-txt-left>
      <cell-tab-txt-left aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="248.94881889754743">
        comparaison maintien/10<superscript>e</superscript>
        rém. de la période de réf. N-1.
      </cell-tab-txt-left>
      <cell-tab-txt-left aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="67.53149606308261">Ind. comp. cp en cours</cell-tab-txt-left>
      <cell-tab-txt-left aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="147.40157480314957">Calculer le droit, au réel + règle des équivalences, jusqu’à la fin du préavis.</cell-tab-txt-left>
      <cell-tab-txt-left aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="248.94881889754743">
        comparaison maintien/10<superscript>e</superscript>
        rém. de la période en cours et jusqu’à la fin du préavis.
      </cell-tab-txt-left>
      <cell-tab-subtit-left aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="3">
        <b>Permet d’obtenir le total du mois représentant du salaire</b>
      </cell-tab-subtit-left>
    </basictable>
```

The result should be

```
<table>
              <tr>
                 <th colspan="3">1.&nbsp;Les «&nbsp;salaires&nbsp;» du mois</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>Salaire mensuel</td>
                 <td>Arrêté à la date de rupture du contrat (fin du préavis, même en cas de dispense par l’employeur).</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>Rappels éventuels</td>
                 <td>Vérifier si des rappels restent dus.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>Primes annuelles</td>
                 <td>Vérifier si les primes annuelles sont dues au prorata.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>Ind. comp. cp N-1</td>
                 <td>Contrôler le solde de cp.</td>
                 <td>
                    comparaison maintien/10
                    <superscript xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/">e</superscript>
                    rém. de la période de réf. N-1.

                 </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>Ind. comp. cp en&nbsp;cours</td>
                 <td>Calculer le droit, au réel&nbsp;+ règle des équivalences, jusqu’à la fin du préavis.</td>
                 <td>
                    comparaison maintien/10
                    <superscript xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/">e</superscript>
                    rém. de la période en cours et jusqu’à la fin du préavis.

                 </td>
              </tr>
             .
             .
             .
           </table>
```

My code:

```
<xsl:template match="cell-tab-txt-right | cell-tab-subtit-left | cell-tab-txt-center | cell-tab-txt-left | cell-tab-subtit-right | cell-tab-subtit-center | cell-tab-tit-center | cell-tab-tit-right | cell-tab-tit-left">
        <xsl:param name="columns" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:if test="$columns != 0">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@aid:ccols = $columns">
                <xsl:element name="tr">
                    <xsl:element name="th">
                        <xsl:attribute name="colspan"><xsl:value-of select="@aid:ccols"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                        </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="tr">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::*[1][position() + (@aid:ccols - 1) $lt; $columns]" mode="list"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? Seems like a good task for XSLT 3's `xsl:iterate`. Or XQuery 3's `window` clause in grouping.

Comment: I use saxon, my version only supports xslt 2.0. I would prefer a solution that works with xslt 2.0, but if that's not possible an upgrade might be the only solution

Comment: Does https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1yaa give the right rows/cells? It is XSLT 3 with `xsl:iterate` which eases such tasks although you can do it with sibling recursion in XSLT 1/2.

Comment: That is correct, that's interesting I might need to check xslt 3.0 out I guess ;). Could you help me out with the sibling recursion I can't seem to get it right in xslt 2.0 because my clients environment is using xslt 2.0

Comment: There are examples of sibling recursion on StackOverflow and I am sure in any text book on XSLT, and I am sure someone else will help you out here.

Comment: Don't tell us that you tried everything and nothing worked. Show us one thing you tried, and tell us how it failed. Then we can see where you went wrong, and explain it to you.

Comment: I tried using the position and adding the amount of extra columns to get them grouped. I know I'm not there yet but I'm stuck on how to get further. I'm quite new to xslt. I added my code for tables. I tried group by and using sum which did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1yaa/2 I have tried to convert the `xsl:iterate` example from the comment to sibling recursion:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="basictable">
      <table>
          <xsl:variable name="max-cols" select="xs:integer(@aid:tcols)"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" mode="row">
              <xsl:with-param name="max-cols" select="$max-cols"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="basictable/*" mode="row">
      <xsl:param name="max-cols"/>
      <xsl:param name="cells" select="()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="current-cells" select="$cells, ."/>
      <xsl:variable name="sum-cells" select="sum($current-cells/@aid:ccols)"/>
      <xsl:if test="$sum-cells eq $max-cols">
          <tr>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="$current-cells"/>
          </tr>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="row">
          <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="if ($sum-cells eq $max-cols) then () else $current-cells"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="max-cols" select="$max-cols"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="basictable/*">
      <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think the grouping of the children of `basictable` into `tr` works the same as the `xsl:iterate` sample, in both samples I have not tried to implement the use of `colspan` and `th` cells as I am not sure what determines that.